# Create applet to send messages on server and get response back

Tags: java, applet

I want to create an applet which should send messages on server and behave according to received response from server.

Can anyone tell me, how can I achieve this. I have tried to find suitable link for this but not succeed.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Aashi

Comment: What's the server? What protocols is it using? Applets tend to run within very strict security models which may prevent you from access external servers outside of it's own server domain

Comment: Actually I am new in applet programming. I have glass fish server and will use NetBeansIDE for this.

Comment: Does it have to be an applet?  It sounds like you are trying to re-invent AJAX.

Comment: So would that HTTP? RMI? Sockets?

Comment: Can you refer some links to me. I have need to create applet as an alternative of ActiveX control. I am very new in this so any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So you're asking for a tutorial on how to do HTTP in Java, right?

Comment: Yes. To send messages from client to server and get response.

Comment: OK, tutorials is not really what Stack Overflow does.  You might find some good information [at this link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) or [at this link](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139).  Both of these could be easily adapted to run as applets.